# Reading in numbers, then adding them in a loop. Bash/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, loops

Help!

I am having big problems finding out how to add numbers that i've written in(read) a loop.
The task im supposed to do is to add X amount of numbers(which I must use read for) then adding them all when "Ctrl+d" is pressed. Im fairly new to linux so please make it as simple as possible :)

Comment: Please provide example in- and output.

Comment: Questions should include your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
while read num;
do
    let sum=sum+num;
done

echo $sum
```

Command：

```
./script.sh
```

Input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
ctrl+D
```

Output:

```
15
```

Answer (score 2):

My favorite trick here employs `bc`:

```
xargs -n1 | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Though you could use bash evaluation if you don't want to use `bc`:

```
sum=$(($(xargs -n1 | paste -sd+)))

echo $sum
```

Comment: -1 for not using a loop as the question says.

Comment: You don't handle tailing linebreaks ("1\n2\n3\n" will become "1+2+3+") which will be there if the input is created using cat > file and terminated by using ^D.

Comment: @Bluewind fixed :) It now handles this: http://ideone.com/4pyUR1

Comment: @sehe aren't you a little bit high rep to be giving answers that don't answer the question?

Comment: @dogbane No, I'm not. I judged the situation as the question being worded overly restrictive, due to inexperience. Right now, I basically see the OP "suspects" he could be doing this in a loop (since that's what he used to generate the numbers).

Comment: @sehe the right way would have been to answer the OP's question and then suggest alternatives. The question clearly says "loop" and "I must use read". Anyway, let's let the OP decide if this is useful or not, instead of bickering amongst ourselves :)

Comment: @dogbane Fair enough. I must say I glossed over "I must use read". Perhaps the "surrounding _incoherence_" just made me see "must read" :/ Troll accusation withdrawn

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input contains one number per line and nothing else, something like this should work:

```
cat $file | tr "\n" "+" | tr -d " " | sed 's/\+$/\n/' | bc
```

(Useless use of cat: This is a example and therefore cat $file represents anything that might output one number per line)

If your numbers aren't integers, you can add the -l option to bc which will enable among other things floating point support.

Comment: Why so complicated :)

Comment: @sehe: Once wrote it and had it lying around and just copied it. Your solution is better though and I remember I once used that too, but forgot about it :(. Thanks.

Comment: -1 for not using a loop as the question says.

Comment: +1 though it does not use loop to do the job, it is still an interesting solution, that I made use of for another problem. Thanks for your answer :]

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

SUM=0
while read NUM && [[ $NUM == +([[:digit:]]) ]]; do
    (( SUM += NUM ))
done

echo "$SUM"
```